# SQL запрос на С# неполучается

Tags: c#, sql

Пишу в SQL следующий запрос :

```
SELECT *
FROM Materials,
     PARAMETERS,
     [Values],
     Suppliers,
     Sensors
WHERE [Values].MaterialId = Materials.Id
  AND [Values].SensorId = Sensors.Id
  AND Materials.SupplierId = Suppliers.Id
  AND PARAMETERS.Id = Sensors.ParameterId
  AND MaterialName='Зерно'
```

все корректно отрабатывает,
 то же самое пытаюсь написать на C# :

```
_comandText = "SELECT * FROM Materials,Parameters,[Values],Suppliers,Sensors WHERE [Values].MaterialId = Materials.Id AND [Values].SensorId = Sensors.Id AND Materials.SupplierId = Suppliers.Id AND Parameters.Id = Sensors.ParameterId";
...
_comandText += " AND MaterialName='" + m.MaterialName + "'";
// _comandText на 100% совпадает с запросом на SQL, я брал его(запрос для SQL) прямо отсюда во время дебага проги
...
private DataTable _table;
...
_table = RaportGateway.Instance.GetRaport(_comandText);
...
 public DataTable GetRaport(string commandText)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, Connection);
            _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            try
            {
                _adapter.Fill(_table);

                return _table;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { // тут ловится Value cannot be null.Parameter name: dataTable, в _table соответственно null
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

почему такое может быть ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private DataTable _table = new DataTable();
```

Comment: Да действительно, исключение пропало, но таблица попрежнему пуста.

Comment: Все разобрался, мои мелкие глупые ошибки.

Comment: не лишним считается выложить полностью рабочий код с решенной ошибкой. а то получается сами себе помогли